# Used to be able to select objects in Pose Mode?

Tags: pose-mode, object-mode

Before, even when I was in Pose Mode with a rig selected I was able to select an object and it would automatically switch to Object Mode. Now I can't and I don't know why.

I don't know when exactly this started happening. I have "Lock Object Modes" unticked.

Anyone have an idea? I must have messed with a setting accidentally or something.

Currently on version 3.5